# If Else Not Work in PHP Script

Tags: php

I have php code to display information messages returned. But this is not working.

This is an example of the codes:

```
<?php
  if(intval(mysql_num_rows($req2))==0) {
?>
  (No reply)
<?php
} else {
?>
  (<?php echo $dn2['reps']-1; ?> time reply)
<?php
}
?>
```

How to fix?

Comment: What is the issue you face? Please specify in detail

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** mysql_* functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements, it really isn't hard.

Comment: If the reply amounted to 0 it will display (no reply) but if no reply will show (1 time reply)

Comment: @Charlotte - How? I still do not understand about php deprecated

Comment: @SigitPurnomo which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html

Comment: @Mauro - I do not know. I can this script from the downloaded. How do you think this version?

Comment: @SigitPurnomo you can what? from the downloaded? run $ php -v in your console/terminal

Comment: As none of the suggestions have helped perhaps if you were to share the code that comes before this would be helpful?!

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use a cleaner code style like:

```
<?php
    if( intval( mysql_num_rows( $req2 ) )===0 ){
        echo '(No reply)';
    } else {
        echo '( '.( $dn2['reps']-1 ).'time reply )';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to debug/read your code. You should always try think about the readability of your code, it's a generally good practice to get into and you'll thank yourself down the road.

So rather than your current approach you could do something along the lines off...

```
<?php

    if (intval(mysql_num_rows($req2)) == 0) {
        $html = '(No Reply)';
    } else {
        $reps = $dn2['reps'] - 1;
        $html = '(' .  htmlspecialchars($reps) . 'time reply)';
    }

    echo $html;
?>
```

I've also added in a `htmlspecialchars()` because you should be escaping any output that you intend to print to the page, otherwise you leave yourself vulnerable to potential injection attacks.

You could also get rid of the `else {}` statement if you wished by altering it to the following:

```
$html = '(No Reply)';
if (mysql_num_rows($req2) > 0) {
    $reps = $dn2['reps'] - 1;
    $html = '(' .  htmlspecialchars($reps) . 'time reply)';
}

echo $html;
```

Also one thing are you 100% sure on the variables names, your if statement seems a little strange. You are checking if `$req2` returns rows, and if it does you are then accessing 'reps' from `$dn2`, just to clarify should that not be `$req2['reps']`?

Comment: Thanks.. Your explanation is very clear, but I still can not apply. I do not know if I was wrong to put the code or how.

Comment: Perhaps you should post the code you are using to pull out $req2 from your database? That could also be a potential reason as to why you are not getting your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

PDO - Php database objects. Depends on version of PHP but its good because of protection against sql injection, object oriented etc. mysql extension will be removed from PHP 7.0. That means if you upgrade, there will be trouble. You can check to see if you have PDO by doing the $phpinfo - and seeing if its listed.

[This is a great article on getting started with it](http://www.sitepoint.com/re-introducing-pdo-the-right-way-to-access-databases-in-php/) - and it explains in detail how it works.